# Trying to get a macro to do steps on google sheet in a specific order

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking to have a macro do certain steps on a sheet in a specific order. We are dealing with 2 TABS in it, but here specifically it's what I want it to do in this order:

In the **"LM Control Sheet"** TAB:

- Copies column K
- Inserts a column to the right of column K
- Pastes values only into column L

Goes to the **"Task1"** TAB

- Deletes data in `A2:B42`, `A44:B79`, `A81:B124`, `A126:B158`

Basically I need it to do it in this order because `K1` has date a formula that is dependent on whatever is in `L1`, so basically, right now for example, `K1`'s formula is yielding `6/17/17 - 6/20/17`.

The formula that is in there actually adds 3 days to the date range based on what `L1` contains, which currently is `6/14/17 - 6/17/17`. The reason I don't want a macro to insert a column between `K` and `L` FIRST, is because the new column `L` will be blank and the formula in `K1` will then yield a date of `"1/2/00 - 1/2/00"`.

If `K` is copied **FIRST**, however and **THEN** pastes values into `L`, it will paste `6/17/17 - 6/20/17` into the new `L` and therefore change the values in `K1` (now `6/20/17 - 6/23/17`).

So yeah that is basically what I am looking to get this macro to do. The macro I was initially given did it out of order but is as follows

```
function myMacro() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var POSht = ss.getSheetByName('LM Control Sheet');
    var PORng = POSht.getDataRange();
    var ASht = ss.getSheetByName('Task1');

    POSht.insertColumnAfter(11);
    var KRng = POSht.getRange(1,11,PORng.getHeight(),1);
    var LRng = POSht.getRange(1,12,PORng.getHeight(),1);

    KRng.copyTo(LRng, {contentsOnly:true});
    ASht.getRange('A2:B42').clearContent();
    ASht.getRange('A44:B79').clearContent();
    ASht.getRange('A81:B124').clearContent();
    ASht.getRange('A126:B158').clearContent();
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```

So any help in reversing that would be awesome. Please and thank you!

Comment: Can you share a link to your spreadsheet.

Comment: I guess I don't know how to insert a column after position 11 (K) without messing up your formulas.  Maybe someone else can help here.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14y35UAt1ELaK25oP6P9tLaM0BdkiGL3bARg5mfGxXzs/edit#gid=14521621

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the spreadsheet access.  I was able to see the problem you were describing.  I think this modification to your macro is what you are looking for.

```
function myMacro()
{
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var POSht = ss.getSheetByName('LM Control Sheet');
var PORng = POSht.getDataRange();
var ASht = ss.getSheetByName('Task1');

var KRng = POSht.getRange(1,11,PORng.getHeight(),1);
var KRngA = KRng.getValues();//save values before inserting new column
POSht.insertColumnAfter(11);
var LRng = POSht.getRange(1,12,PORng.getHeight(),1);//get range for copying values
LRng.setValues(KRngA);//insert old values from K into the new column

ASht.getRange('A2:B42').clearContent();
ASht.getRange('A44:B79').clearContent();
ASht.getRange('A81:B124').clearContent();
ASht.getRange('A126:B158').clearContent();
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That works perfectly. I now have more automation on that sheet. Many thanks to you for this help!